# Keypad encoder why with 8 states?

Tags: vhdl, state-machine, keypad

I need to code in vhdl a keypad encoder. I was thinking to make it with 4 states. when at columnn1 scan row1,row2,row2,row4. 4 states like this should be enough according to me but an example I found from the internet makes it with 8 states:

```
key_scanner_sm : process (clk)
  begin  -- process key_scanner
    if clk'event and clk = '1' then

      if state_inc = '1' then

        -- reset scan_complete
        scan_complete <= '0';

        case key_state is

          when pulse_row_1 =>
            key_read  <= (others => '0');
            key_row   <= "0001";
            key_state <= read_row_1;

          when read_row_1 =>
            case key_col is
              when "0001" => key_read <= X"31";  -- 1
              when "0010" => key_read <= X"32";  -- 2
              when "0100" => key_read <= X"33";  -- 3
              when "1000" => key_read <= X"41";  -- A
              when others => null;
            end case;
            key_state <= pulse_row_2;

          when pulse_row_2 =>
            key_row   <= "0010";
            key_state <= read_row_2;

          when read_row_2 =>
            case key_col is
              when "0001" => key_read <= X"34";  -- 4
              when "0010" => key_read <= X"35";  -- 5
              when "0100" => key_read <= X"36";  -- 6
              when "1000" => key_read <= X"42";  -- B
              when others => null;
            end case;
            key_state <= pulse_row_3;

          when pulse_row_3 =>
            key_row   <= "0100";
            key_state <= read_row_3;

          when read_row_3 =>
            case key_col is
              when "0001" => key_read <= X"37";  -- 7
              when "0010" => key_read <= X"38";  -- 8
              when "0100" => key_read <= X"39";  -- 9
              when "1000" => key_read <= X"43";  -- C
              when others => null;
            end case;
            key_state <= pulse_row_4;

          when pulse_row_4 =>
            key_row   <= "1000";
            key_state <= read_row_4;

          when read_row_4 =>
            case key_col is
              when "0001" => key_read <= X"2A";  -- *
              when "0010" => key_read <= X"30";  -- 0
              when "0100" => key_read <= X"23";  -- #
              when "1000" => key_read <= X"44";  -- D
              when others => null;
            end case;
            key_state     <= pulse_row_1;
            scan_complete <= '1';

          when others => null;
        end case;

      end if;
    end if;
  end process key_scanner_sm;
```

Is there a good reason behind this, does anybody know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you provide needs the extra states because it is implemented as a single case statement. The assignment to `key_row` needs an extra cycle to take effect before `key_col` can be read. Since this is a simple cyclic scan the `pulse_row_n` states could be eliminated by assigning the next value of `key_row` from the preceding `read_row_n` state

Comment: So we can simply write this in 4 states, I just don't get why the coder did it in 8 states? Why make it more complicated? Im looking for a good reason behind this, is there? To protect for example from a situation like 2 buttons pressed etc.?

Comment: They didn't realize the opportunity to trim some states. Most of the VHDL code you see floating around online is poor to middling quality. It doesn't always represent best practices. In this case it doesn't matter that cycles are wasted since this is a small bit of logic and is fast enough for human interaction. What you need to be mindful of is implementing filters to debounce the matrix inputs to avoid recording multiple presses from a bouncy button. You also need to synchronize the `key_col` inputs to your clock domain before feeding the external signals directly into a debounce filter.

Comment: One example of things to avoid is the VHDL-87 style clock'event and clock ='1' boilerplate for synchronous processes. You should use the VHDL-93 rising_edge function since it has an internal call to to_X01 to perform strength reduction on the clock signal before testing it. This is more readable, and is important for correct behavior in simulation situations where the clock could be 'H' or 'L'. Lots of modern VHDL is still coded the old way because of poorly written, out of date instructional materials. When I see VHDL-87 in code less than 15 years old I am suspicious of its quality.

Comment: Right debouncing is very important and I asked it here already with a bounty, I would be glad if you can help me there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434772/state-machine-why-only-last-state-is-working/

Comment: You need to keep the reset in the design. See [my comments on this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493970/trying-to-make-a-more-elegant-solution-to-this-clock-stretcher#comment36039447_23493970) for more explanation why. If you aren't making production hardware it is ok to use an external switch to control reset, otherwise consider using the advice on generating an internal reset.